# How to save an Excel file every, say one minute?

Tags: excel, vba

Are there some macros which can do it?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3i6hf8/code_in_vba_to_automatically_save_a_file_every_15/

Comment: Excel has an [option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Help-protect-your-files-in-case-of-a-crash-551c29b1-6a4b-4415-a3ff-a80415b92f99#ID0EAAEAAA=2016,_2013,_2010) to auto-save every X minutes.

Comment: @MatSnow Thank you for your comment ! I do not quite understand where the autosave file is saved ? Where can I find it ? I mean I see that original file is NOT saved every minute even if I put autosave = 1 - probably Excel saves copy to some its internal directory

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Excel saves auto-recovery information in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel` by default. Path can be changed in options.

Comment: @MatSnow Thank you very much for your advise ! There are several issues I cannot resolve 1 ) AutoSave fies have extension .xlsb - and Python Pandas CANNOT open it 2) It seems that autosave does really works in the way I understand  - I do not see new files each minute it seems it creates several files (5) and after 5-th is saved it rewrites file number one

Comment: @AlexanderChervov If you need to open the files with another software than Excel, then KresimirL.'s answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please put this code in `ThisWorkbook module`. you can access this module by pressing double click on ThisWorkbook module inside VBA project.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

[image]

then put this code in `standard module`. To insert standard module, right click on VBA project==>Insert==>Module. then paste code in newly created module.

[image]

```
Sub Save1()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

Now when you open your workbook, it will automatically save every minute. You need to reopen Workbook in order to trigger `Workboook_Open` event.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and fast answer ! If it is possible , would you be so kind to comment what means "ThisWorkbook module" and "standard module", I am not sure I understand VBA basics. I thought one needs to create button and attach macroses to buttons, but it seems you are not using that way.

Comment: HI, please see edited answer. you can also find mora about it [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955461/what-difference-does-it-make-if-one-runs-a-vba-code-in-sheets-in-thisworkboo) could you please accept answer?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will accept your answer, but still I have one more issue - can I start the module without REopening the file ? Something like "start" button ? Because - if I save file it will be *.xlsm, but the stream of data which I need to store does not support that kind of file

Comment: You can assign Save1 macro to a button and then run it, but you will still need to save file as .xlsm or .xls or .xlsb in order to preserve macro after you exit workbook.

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550958/how-to-save-all-excel-files-every-say-minute-10-seconds

Comment: Application.OnTime is a method of the Application object. hence the autosave loop will only terminate once Excel gets closed (not the Workbook). Leading to potentially having multiple autosave loops running simultainioulsy (if you reopen the workbook). To avoid this you should terminate OnTime calls before you close the workbook (see my answer below)

Comment: Your solution will fail if another user opens the file while you have it open.  You need to handle when the file is opened as Read Only.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer while working has a problem:

`Application.OnTime` is as you can tell by how you call it; a method of the `Application` object. Meaning it is not called from any specific Workbook/sheet, but from the Application Excel itself. Meaning as long as Excel is open it will keep on running.

So if you have a second (unrelated) Workbook open and close the one where you've implemented the auto-save feature, the code for autosaving will just keep on running. If you now open the autosaving Workbook again you'll suddenly have 2 autosave loops running. So 2 autosaves per 30 sec. Do it again and you'll have 3 autosave loops running simultainiously.

The autoSave loop will only terminate if you close Excel completely.

This issue can be fixed, by terminating the OnTime calls before you close the Workbook. You can do this as shown below:

NormalModule:

```
Global saveTimer As Variant

Sub Save1()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    saveTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime saveTimer, "Save1"
End Sub
```

WorkbookModule:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnTime saveTimer, "Save1", , False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    saveTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime saveTimer, "Save1"
End Sub
```

With this code, the currently running `OnTime` call will be terminated if you close the workbook.