# How to save ALL Excel files every say minute / 10 seconds?

Tags: excel, vba

**Question:** How to save ALL Excel files every given time period - say every minute or every 10 seconds ?

**Related:** here [How to save Excel file every say minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46524488/625396) a way to save given file is described. But if I have many files it is a problem to process like that.

**Remark:** 
In case if I need to save every minute - I can use Excel's autosave, but 
autosave is is in *.xlsb format which I have a problem reading by Python,
also several files are created and it is not clear what file is saved in what moment.
Also that would not work if I need to save every 10 seconds.

Comment: You would need to put the autosave macro in the Personal Workbook.  Check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790) and this [link](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm) for information on how to access it and what it is. Then in the actual code replace all instances of `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save all **open** excel files every 10 seconds, you can use this code. You can assign it to shape and run it from one of the excel files.

```
Sub Save1()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWb In Application.Workbooks
        If Not xWb.ReadOnly And Windows(xWb.Name).Visible Then
            xWb.Save
        End If
    Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Just some comments for myself to remember: 1) that code can be inserted in some new "module" ( created by project==>Insert==>Module ) 2) create some Button and write code : Call Save1   ---------- it works fine, and pressing button starts the whole process