# Excel macro: other user wants to get latest content of open workbook

Tags: excel, vba, autosave

I have a (possibly very silly) question about Excel macros but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else. My problem is this:
I have an Excel file open all day and I updated it throughout the day when needed.
My boss has another Excel file with a macro. Whenever he runs that macro, he is supposed to get the latest information from my file into his spreadsheet. What he actually gets though is the information from the last point I saved my file. So, even though I've set autosave to run every minute, if I last saved my file 2hrs ago, my boss will see my contents as off 2hrs ago and not anything else I've done since then.
Is there anyway to bypass this without the macro closing/saving/interfering with my file at all?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: An autosave is not the same thing as a save.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524488/how-to-save-excel-file-every-say-minute This is what you want, right ?

Comment: Depending on how many times the boss needs to run the macro, perhaps the easiest solution is to have him simply ask you to save, so he can run it?  Or perhaps give a sign like raise his hand, that'd be a visually basic application I think.

Comment: Maybe MS-Access is a better tool for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! I'm new to VBA and this forum so took me a while to see all your answers. Indeed they are all very helpful and seem to approach my question in ways I didn't know existed, so thanks for that. It's really difficult to search for things when you don't know what you are looking for (so thanks to those that gave my post a negative rating, it really helped!). I'm actually using a macro in my file so it just dawned on me that I can just simply add the  autosave in there, so problem solved! Apologies for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you would love it if your workbook saved every single time anything changed on it, now that the formatting and arrangement are the way you want it.  This way, the moment you hit ENTER on your keyboard, the file would be accessible to your boss.

I suggest forcing your workbook to save every time something changes.  Add this code to the worksheet_change event:

```
Activeworkbook.save
```

Find the worksheet_change event like this:

[image]

Note that this code will make you crazy if it takes a long time to save or if you have a lot of things to change all at once.  So be prepared to get rid of it.  (Hit Alt-F11 to access the programming window)

Somebody smarter than me wrote some more about doing this, when the updates affect only a certain range of cells... 
http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/using-macros-to-save-workbooks-when-cells-change/

Have fun!

Comment: I've tried to make the transition to MS Access with a tracking spreadsheet and it was too much for me.  Excel is pretty good, after all, and why not just hotrod / overclock / hack / mod / overdrive it a little bit?

Comment: Thank you very much Elliot! I'll try that but indeed I don't want the file to save each time I hit enter as it might take longer to do anything on it. But I'll definitely try it! Thanks!

Comment: M.Douda's proposal is a great choice, too--- saving every minute.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524488/how-to-save-excel-file-every-say-minute

Comment: It only saves when you hit ENTER in case you were editing the cell... moving about with TAB, ENTER, and arrow keys shouldn't cause it to save, I think.

Comment: This might be a good candidate for SharePoint Lists.  (MS-haters look away)  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-lists-i-an-introduction-f11cd5fe-bc87-4f9e-9bfe-bbd87a22a194