# Hiding Saving Window Occurring Every Instance in a For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a Honeywell scanner to input a string of numbers into an excel file, and applying a timestamp when a scan is performed. This excel database is connected to PowerBI Desktop, and so in order to have a live count, I need to save the file after each scanning instance. To do this I use the following code:

```
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 1 To 3
StartHandler:

If i Mod 1 = 0 Then
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
ans = InputBox("Please Scan Pad-Pak Box", "Data Entry Form")
If ans = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Scan was unsuccessful, please try again")
GoTo StartHandler

Else
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & lr).Value = ans

End If
Next
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The code works as intended except that the saving window shows up everytime I scan. I have (as per the code) tried to use `application.displayalerts = false` and placed it inside and outside the For loop but it didn't work for either. Any tips?

Goal: To perform the macro whilst hiding the saving window (shown below)

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that this window does not belong to Excel. So, any `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will not help. It stops only Excel application showing alerts. If this is annoying you can try to build a Timer in a module, looking for the window having caption "Saving" and hide it using API. But, this hiding will not speed up your code. It will anyhow wait for the saving to be finished... If you have a big file, it may take longer.

Comment: You could use a different workbook and update the spreadsheet linked to power bi, by SQL and ADO.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru Thanks for getting in touch! I tried using this set-up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524488/how-to-save-an-excel-file-every-say-one-minute but it didn't seem to work with my macro - I have a loop of inputboxes, and it didn't seem to save it every minute... I would only be scanning every minute at best, unless there is another workaround you can think of

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, would you be able to elaborate on your answer/provide links to something similar perhaps? I am not very familiar with SQL and ADO. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @bewislammeld: How much the saving in discussion takes? I told you that the window in discussion does not belong to Excel and your concern should be pointing to necessary saving time, I think... Decrease the workbook size, for instance.

Comment: @FaneDuru, I guess with it saving every minute on average that it won't impede too much on the system, so will trial it as is and see if there are anymore limitations. Thanks for the heads up /info :)

Comment: First, why do you constantly save in each iteration of the loop? Second, this dialog appears, if your workbook is on network.

Comment: Hi @JohnyL I have connected my excel workbook to a powerBI report and it will only update the scan count after each instance is saved in the excel file - I am open to other software platform suggestions for doing a live count after scanning each item. 2. That is a very good point, I moved the file to the onedrive and it didn't appear, but I thought that it wasn't working but that may explain it!

Comment: Try moving it to local drive and see if this dialog will appear again.

Comment: @bewislammeld It's best that you google it, do a bit of research and get your head around it, rather than me show you code, you wont fully undetstand.